# Android BluetoothSocket::connect() throws an exception

Tags: java, android, sockets, exception, bluetooth

I can not initiate the bluetooth connection between Java server(using `bluecove 2.1.1 on Windows 7 x64, external bluetooth dongle`) and `Android` client(OS version 2.3.6).

Device discovery works normally, but I cannot connect to service running on PC(`BluetoothSocket::connect() throw an exception`). Below is a very primitive version of server and client(I use `MAC address` of `bluetooth dongle` for reducing code length):

Java Server

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.microedition.io.*;
import javax.bluetooth.*;

public class RFCOMMServer {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {

        StreamConnectionNotifier service = (StreamConnectionNotifier) Connector
                .open("btspp://localhost:"
                        + new UUID("0000110100001000800000805F9B34FB",
                                false).toString() + ";name=helloService");

        StreamConnection conn = (StreamConnection) service.acceptAndOpen();
        System.out.println("Connected");

        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(conn.openInputStream());
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(conn.openOutputStream());

        String received = in.readUTF();         // Read from client
        System.out.println("received: " + received);

        out.writeUTF("Echo: " + received);      // Send Echo to client

        conn.close();
        service.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.print(e.toString());
    }
}
}
```

Android Client

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class AndroidBluetoothEchoClientActivity extends ListActivity {
LinearLayout layout;

private ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter;

final Handler handler = new Handler();

final Runnable updateUI = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mArrayAdapter.add(bluetoothClient.getBluetoothClientData());
    }
};

BluetoothClient bluetoothClient;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    this.setListAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
    bluetoothClient = new BluetoothClient(handler, updateUI);
    bluetoothClient.start();
}
}

class BluetoothClient extends Thread {

BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private String data = null;

final Handler handler;
final Runnable updateUI;

public BluetoothClient(Handler handler, Runnable updateUI) {
    this.handler = handler;
    this.updateUI = updateUI;

    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
}

public String getBluetoothClientData() {
    return data;
}

public void run() {
    BluetoothSocket clientSocket = null;
                                        // Client knows the MAC address of server
    BluetoothDevice mmDevice = mBluetoothAdapter
            .getRemoteDevice("00:15:83:07:CE:27");

    try {

        clientSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID
                .fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));

        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        clientSocket.connect();
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

        out.writeUTF("Hello");          // Send to server

        data = in.readUTF();            // Read from server
        handler.post(updateUI);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
}
```

Here is core of the problem(I guess):

```
BluetoothDevice mmDevice = mBluetoothAdapter
            .getRemoteDevice("00:15:83:07:CE:27");//normally get device

    try {

        clientSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID
                .fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));//here also no problem

        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        clientSocket.connect();//here throw an exception
```

I try to use reflection:

```
Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
clientSocket  = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
```

but it also not work.

For over a week I can not solve this problem, I would be grateful if you help with the decision.

Here is the log file:

```
02-27 08:32:33.656: W/ActivityThread(10335): Application edu.ius.rwisman.AndroidBluetoothEchoClient is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
02-27 08:32:33.687: I/System.out(10335): Sending WAIT chunk
02-27 08:32:33.882: I/System.out(10335): Debugger has connected
02-27 08:32:33.882: I/System.out(10335): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-27 08:32:34.085: I/System.out(10335): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-27 08:32:34.289: I/System.out(10335): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-27 08:32:34.492: I/System.out(10335): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-27 08:32:34.687: I/System.out(10335): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-27 08:32:34.890: I/System.out(10335): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-27 08:32:35.093: I/System.out(10335): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-27 08:32:35.296: I/System.out(10335): debugger has settled (1493)
02-27 08:32:35.390: I/ApplicationPackageManager(10335): cscCountry is not German : SER
02-27 08:32:35.875: D/dalvikvm(10335): threadid=9: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
02-27 08:32:45.351: D/BluetoothSocket(10335): create BluetoothSocket: type = 1, fd = -1, uuid = [00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb], port = -1
02-27 08:32:45.351: D/BLZ20_WRAPPER(10335): blz20_init: initializing...
02-27 08:32:45.351: D/BTL_IFC_WRP(10335): wsactive_init: init active list
02-27 08:32:45.460: D/BLZ20_WRAPPER(10335): blz20_init: success
02-27 08:32:45.460: D/BTL_IFC_WRP(10335): wrp_sock_create: CTRL
02-27 08:32:45.460: D/BTL_IFC_WRP(10335): wrp_alloc_new_sock: wrp_alloc_new_sock sub 1
02-27 08:32:45.460: D/BTL_IFC_WRP(10335): wrp_sock_create: 43
02-27 08:32:45.460: D/BTL_IFC_WRP(10335): wrp_sock_connect: wrp_sock_connect brcm.bt.btlif:9000 (43)
02-27 08:32:45.460: D/BTL_IFC_WRP(10335): wrp_sock_connect: BTLIF_MAKE_LOCAL_SERVER_NAME return name: brcm.bt.btlif.9000
02-27 08:32:45.460: D/BTL_IFC_WRP(10335): wrp_sock_connect: wrp_sock_connect ret:-1 server name:brcm.bt.btlif.9000
02-27 08:32:45.460: E/BTL_IFC_WRP(10335): ##### ERROR : wrp_sock_connect: connect failed (Connection refused)#####
02-27 08:32:45.460: E/BTL_IFC(10335): ##### ERROR : btl_ifc_ctrl_connect: control channel failed Connection refused#####
02-27 08:32:45.460: D/BTL_IFC_WRP(10335): wrp_close_full: wrp_close (43:-1) [brcm.bt.btlif]
02-27 08:32:45.460: D/BTL_IFC_WRP(10335): wsactive_del: delete wsock 43 from active list [ad3bc380]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, simply verification code on my device and on PC was different, but Windows shown device in paired devices list. I repair device and it works.